# How do you actually pronounce the vowels that form a synalepha/sinalefe, specifically when singing?

Tags: pronunciation

The "sinalefe" is a well-known element in Italian prosody, in which two vowels, at the end and at the beginning of a word are "combined". But how is this combination actually pronounced, especially when singing?  Are the two vowels pronounced quickly together, at the time reserved for a single syllable? Or is one of the vowels (presumably the first one) elided completely?

Comment: I let someone else answer about singing, but when you read poetry – at least in my experience – you definitely read both vowels, otherwise the meaning itself would change or be unclear. “In una selva oscura” doesn't become “selvascura”, nor “selvoscura”. The two vowels are pronounced in a kind of diphthong (not an actual one, since in Italian only certain couple of sounds are considered to form a diphthong).

Answer (score 3):

A good example is the chorus “Va’, pensiero” from “Nabuccodonosor” (usually simply called “Nabucco”).

> Va’, pensiero, sull'ali dorate
> Va’, ti posa sui clivi, sui colli
> Ove olezzano tepide e molli
> L'aure dolci del suolo natal.

The verses are *decasillabi*. The division into syllables would be

> va/pen/sie/ro/sul/la/li/do/ra/te
> va/ti/po/sa/sui/cli/vi/sui/col/li
> o/ve͜o/lez/za/no/te/pi/de͜e/mol/li
> lau/re/dol/ci/del/suo/lo/na/tal

The last verse is typically only nine syllables long, because the last word becomes oxytone via truncation.

There are two examples of synalepha in the third verse. The vowels are pronounced together as if they formed a diphthong; in the second case they are simply merged into one.

Hear it at 1:41 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBYmhYxEvUM

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify for the sake of foreign students' understanding, sinalefe is just a technical device for counting syllables in poetry, it doesn't affect the way words are pronounced.

Comment: This is not completely true - the vowels composing a synalepha are pronounced more "smooshed together", in a single breath (although it is true that they are still individually distinguishable).